# Need help to handle a case of "deferred sending rule"

Tags: outlook-addin

I have a VSTO addin with Outlook. I currently use the Send Folder in my Items.ItemAdd() event to intercept the email to process and save it into a depository, BUT in the case of "deferred sending rule" or Outlook is not online for any reason, the emails will be stuck in the Outbox during that time, our Items.ItemAdd() could not process the emails properly if user sends a bunch of emails. So I try to change it to use Outbox folder in my Items.ItemAdd event instead, BUT then I find out that in the non-Cached Exchange Mode (turn it off), the item in Items.ItemAdd(item) event is stale (if the Cached Exchange Mode is on, it works OK).
Not sure how to handle it properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better yet decision is to handle the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event of the `Application` class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program.

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 
 
Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim prompt As String 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
   Cancel = True
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. The issue now is that when I save it to a depository during this event, the item in myOlApp_ItemSend() doesn't have a From field, subject or body of the email yet? Whereas, in my current logic, the email in Outbox folder (or Send Folder when I original used) when I use the Items.ItemAdd() event, has all the fields so after I save it to a depository, I could see all the fields. I use C#.

Comment: Then I'd suggest using a timer. In the timer's tick event you can check the sent items periodically.